# EF: Non-nullable UpdateException for NotMapped property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, .net-4.6.1

I am syncing data periodically on my ASP.NET page.  I have an object with two complex members, which I am ignoring in Entity Framework using the NotMapped attribute.  Instead, I store serialized values.

Models:

```
public class Game
{
    //...
    [NotMapped]
    public Image Image { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

    public string Image_Serialized
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Image);
        }
        set
        {
            Image = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Image>(value);
        }
    }

    public string Images_Serialized
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Images);
        }
        set
        {
            Images = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Image>>(value);
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

And...

```
public class Image
{
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }
    public string MediumUrl { get; set; }
    public string ScreenUrl { get; set; }
    public string SmallUrl { get; set; }
    public string SuperUrl { get; set; }
    public string ThumbUrl { get; set; }
    public string TinyUrl { get; set; }
}
```

When my sync is complete, I update my database:

```
foreach(var game in games)
{
    // address any null complex types.
    if (game.Image == null) game.Image = new Image();
    if (game.Images == null) game.Images = new List<Image>();

    // add game if new, update if already in db
    var dbGame = db.Games.Where(g => g.Id == game.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (dbGame == null)
    {
        db.Games.Add(game);
    }
    else
    {
        var queriedGame = db.Entry(dbGame);
        queriedGame.CurrentValues.SetValues(game);
        queriedGame.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }

}

// returns 0 results... seems fine
var badGames = games.Where(g => g.Image == null || g.Images == null).ToList();

db.SaveChanges();
```

I receive the following exception at db.SaveChanges():

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'Image'.
```

Thank you for any help.  Additionally, why do I need to worry about these values being null if I'm not expecting their values to be directly stored in the db (NotMapped attribute)?

Comment: What is the reason for saving image as serialized string then an image id in the game object?

Comment: check the Game table if it has a column Image?

Comment: @AliBaig That's not what is happening. There is a featured Image, and a list of related Images.  These are all URLs which link to images on an external server.  The featured image does not necessarily exist in the related list.

Comment: @TarekAboELkheir Game table doesn't have an Image column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to Ali for sending me in the right direction.

After changing the Image to a struct, and making the Image reference nullable, I still had the same error.  The issue was that the Game object was referencing a number of other object types (Developer, Publisher, Release, etc).  Some of these objects had Image references in them which I had not yet set to NotMapped.  My hypothesis is that when I called db.SaveChanges(), it was trying to add entries to these data tables, and causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would not advise you to use such a model instead have image id in your game class with a `ICollection` of images (infact why even have both).

Having said that with the current model, you can try something like

```
public class Game
{
    //...
    [NotMapped]
    public Image? Image { get; set; }  //<== see ? to make it nullable

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

    public string Image_Serialized
    {
        get
        {
            if(Image == null)
                return null;
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Image);
        }
        set
        {
            if(value == null)
                Image = null;
            else
                Image = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Image>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  Why is Image not nullable by default? It is an object.  Is this simply a decoration for the EF to understand?

Better question - Why does entity framework care if Image is null, when it is NotMapped?

Comment: Image is currently an object, which means it is already nullable by definition. Adding the ? decoration gives me the error "Image must be a non-nullable value type." This requires me to be using a struct (non-nullable type). I can try that, but I am using another person's library for this. I'd prefer not to change his object to a struct.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use Image? instead of Image as data type.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I don't follow... Image is an abstract data type that I created.

Comment: Do you know about nullable types in c#?
Check out the documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: Yes, but nullable types are intended for objects which can't be nullable (structs, primitives, etc).  This is an object, which by its very nature is nullable.  I'm not certain how that would help me here.  Could you explain?

Comment: The nullable type can also be used for abstract datatypes. The error message is telling you that you treat Image as a non-nullable type, but it is being used as a nullable type. I am certain using Image? will fix the problem.

Comment: Image is currently an object, which means it is already nullable by definition.  Adding the ? decoration gives me the error "Image must be a non-nullable value type." This requires me to be using a struct (non-nullable type).  I can try that, but I am using another person's library for this.  I'd prefer not to change his object to a struct.